# Can I use multiple routes in same Laravel project?

Tags: laravel

I have a laravel project that will manage multiple team.

I need to define multiple routes for particular team.

Is that possible ?

Comment: What do you mean by Multiple routes?

Comment: There are more than one routes page same or different path.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes you can in your `RouteServiceProvider.php` file `App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider` you can add your custom route file like this in `map` method

```
    $router->group(['namespace' => YOUR_NAMESPACE], function ($router) {
        require app_path(YOUR_PATH_TO_ROUTE_FILE);
    });
```

Or you can create a custom service provider & from that file you can register your custom routes.

```
namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class YOURCUSTOMSERVICEPROVIDER extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Bootstrap the application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        if (! $this->app->routesAreCached()) {
            require YOUR_PATH_TO_ROUTE_FILE;
        }
    }
}
```

You can learn more from https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/routing, https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/providers & https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/packages#routing